# How can I keep a rug from moving?

Tags: carpet

Not sure if this is the right place for this question but....

I have a rug that is about 15x20 feet.  My problem is that every three weeks or so I need to take everything that is on top of it (coffee table, couch legs, entertainment center etc) off and straighten it out because it either gets tilted in such a way that it doesn't line up with the walls any longer or bunches up in the middle at certain spots.

Does anyone know of a way to keep it from moving around?  Is there something I could use to attach it to the carpet below (without damaging the carpet)?

Comment: When you place an area rug on top of a carpet, you're fighting the grain of the bottom carpet. Pads may help, but I've only seen them used to avoid sliding on hardwood. The same thing happens with chair mats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is double-sided "rug gripper" tape available at Target and Home Depot (probably most other stores, but I know those two carry it).

We use it to keep our entry rugs stuck to the tiled floor.  It holds well enough that we can vacuum the rugs.

Disclaimer:  Not sure how well it will stick to a carpet vs a hard floor.

Alternatively you could use rug pins/rug anchors to hold the area rugs to your carpet.

Answer (score 13):

They make rug pads just for this:

[image: Picture of a rug pad]

You can find them at any big-box home improvement store.

Comment: I have these and they help, but things still move. I have a rug with a built-in non-slip pad and it stays put really well.

Answer (score 1):

There is special double-sided tape to help keep your rug from moving. It helps to keep a two-inch gap between the tape and the edge of your carpet. There are also anti-slip pads you can place under strategic areas of your carpet to ensure less bunching up and movement over time.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a carpet liner or pad to keep a rug from sliding. There are many types, but I recommend natural fiber that is colored the same color as your carpet underneath.

Some fiber options include felt, horsehair, and jute. Felt is a personal favorite. Rubber and foam are the other options, but in my experience they bind and bunch and you can feel it underneath the rug.
When using a carpet pad, it is imperative that you pay extra attention to liquid spills as the pad will compound any moisture issues, ie... it will expedite rotting if not taken care of, but this is true with any liner you use.

You can details about each [here](http://www.baneclene.com/articles/carpet-cushion.html).